# Error 438 when populating VBA ActiveX combobox only on some computers

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have created a Workbook  with ActiveX Combo Box controls that populate through worksheet_activate() code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()    
   With ActiveSheet.cmboBox1
        .Clear
        .AddItem "Item 1"
        .AddItem "Item 2"
        .AddItem "etc..."
        .Text = "Select... "
        .Width = 222
        .Height = 19
        .Left = 0
        .Top = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

This works fine on my computer. However, when I attempt to open the spreadsheet on my colleagues' computers they receive Error 438 and the debug highlights the line:

```
With ActiveSheet.cmboBox1
```

I have compared Excel versions and we're running exactly the same versions.

We have the same ActiveX Trust Centre settings.
I have created a blank worksheet with just the one ActiveX combo box and the same thing happens.

I have tried specifying the worksheet directly in lieu of using ActiveSheet, but the problem persists.

I was so close to going live with my code and then this! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simple diagnostic is that the active sheet does not have a member named "cmboBox1".  They normally don't of course, just adding a sheet is enough to bomb the code.  A spelling error is an easy mistake as well given that the default name is "ComboBox1".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I looked at that, but these sheets activate and work fine on my machine. It's only when I move to another computer and open the same workbooks that this error eventuates.

Comment: Why don't you use the sheet's name instead pf `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: Thanks Paulo. As mentioned in my original post referencing the worksheet directly has the same effect. For example, using `With Sheets("Sheet1").cmboBox1` generates the same problem on my colleagues' computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally determined the cause of the problem. 
Once more, it's been caused by a Microsoft Security Update (that had somehow been installed on my colleagues' computers and not mine). Refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036

After running the patch from that KB article, it all worked again.